# Php making a form entry

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a PHP project of tours and travels company and I have done adding everything but I am messing up with the buy now form which requires user's name, address, etc.

I cant find any way to get the package name or id from the previous page that is stored in database.

Please help if you can help me figure out this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add some code here to provide context otherwise this question requires a crystal ball to answer. We cannot guess your intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save form data in a multistep process, you typically need to insert it with a known value. This can be done with php's `uuid()` function.

1. Generate a value with `uuid()`
2. Ensure that the value returned by `uuid()` isn't already used. For a low traffic website the probability is low, but you should definitely still check!
3. If the value is not unique to your database, loop to step 1. If you have a unique value continue to step 4.
4. Insert the first part of your records with the uuid.
5. Insert the rest of your records. The uuid value you generated is now how you'll link the records.

If you don't want to change your DB's foreign key structure, you can use a select statement to pull the primary key that was generated by whatever process you've already setup by selecting the uuid.